# Magento New Product Attribute Not Saving

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, post-data

I am having an issue in Magento where custom product attributes are not updating.

When setting the new attributes under Catalog->Manage Products->*Product*->General, the post data for that specific attribute of the product contains a null value. As such, the attribute is set to 0 in the case of one attribute, and null in the case of the second attribute. Here is the code I used to add the attributes.

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','sigis_gtin', array(
    'group' => 'General',
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'SIGIS GTIN',
    'input' => 'text',
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => 1,
));

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','sigis_eligible', array(
    'group' => 'General',
    'type' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Sigis Eligibility',
    'input' => 'select',
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'unique' => 0,
    'default' => 0,
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

My question is: Why is the Manage Product page sending null data, which in turn makes it so my changes don't save?

Answer (score 2):

you can try adding this attribute to product attribute set.
[image]

Comment: I have verified that it is in the Product Details attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

You got 0 value for the second attribute and null for the first one just because you declared a default value as 0 for the second and nothing in the first.

having these values saved means both of your attributes are not saved.

Check that the both of them are in your product attribute set (if not drag and drop them from unassigned to which group you want).

Also check in which store scope have you edited your product it may be null in default scope but not null in store scope.

Comment: I've verified that the attribute is in the proper attribute set. I've also verified that the store scope is correct.

Comment: Do you have a big set of data in your database ? if yes let me know if the increment_id of your catalog_product_entity_int and catalog_product_entity_varchar are lower than (2147483648)

Answer (score 0):

I had a tab on the Catalog->Manage Products->*Product* page on the left hand side that contained an input field with the same name as the attribute I was editing. After deleting that field from the tab, the issue was resolved.